# Dialogflow middleware not working with Botkit

Tags: dialogflow-es, botkit

I've created a FB chatbot with botkit and I'm trying to connect a dialogflow middleware.

For some reason, when I connect the middleware like so I don't get any response:

**bot.js**:

```
var dialogflowMiddleware = require('botkit-middleware-dialogflow')({
  token: process.env.dialogflow
});

controller.middleware.receive.use(dialogflowMiddleware.receive);

controller.hears('test', 'message_received', dialogflowMiddleware.hears, function(
    bot,
    message
) {
  console.log('MESSAGE:', message);
    bot.reply(message, 'Hello!');
});
```

Things I've done:

- Use Dialogflow API v1
- Use correct client access token
- Corretly named my intent 'test'
- Removed the middleware and tested it was working (to ensure problem is down to something else)

Comment: Do you still facing this issue ?

Comment: Not anymore. I think the problem was that I was declaring the middleware after setting up the webserver : `var webserver = require(__dirname + '/components/express_webserver.js')(controller);
`